# Access to controller scope from $scope.$on in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, event-handling, angularjs-scope

I'm beginner at Angular and I have this simple problem in Angular 1.5. I use rootScope for emit some events and $scope.$on as the event listener in component controller (which provide data for child components). This controller contains some complex object, which must be modified by incoming event data. 
Controller looks like this (just example):

```
function ComponentController($scope){

  this.abc = 5;

  $scope.$on('BOOM!', function(events, args){
    console.log(args);
    this.abc = this.abc + args;  // example of modifying some controllers data
  })
}
```

Problem is clear - I can't modify *this.abc*. So how can I access to controllers data and modify them within this event listener? When I use *$scope.abc* instead, it works, but is it necessary (when I use everywhere controllerAs)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should solve your issue

```
function ComponentController($scope){
  var vm = this;
  vm.abc = 5;

  $scope.$on('BOOM!', function(events, args){
    console.log(args);
    vm.abc = vm.abc + args;  // example of modifying some controllers data
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks. it works. The problem is just in the scope (event listener has own scope with own this)? I didnt thought that before.

Answer (score 0):

```
function ComponentController($scope){
  //Assign this to that, this is in the scope/context of ComponentController.   
  var that = this.
  that.abc = 5;

  $scope.$on('BOOM!', function(events, args){
    //the this used here earlier was in the scope/context of the function to handle this event
    // therefore we use the that variable assigned in the ComponentController.
    console.log(args);
    that.abc = that.abc + args;  // example of modifying some controllers data
  })
}
```